# Hurricane Graphics: Help with Coloring a Graph

Tags: plotting, color, curated-data, geography, geodesy

So currently I have a graph of latitude, longitude, and Max Rainfall generated from the code below.

```
dallas = CityData[{"Dallas", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}, "Coordinates"];

With[{n = 400}, weatherStations = WeatherData[{dallas, n}]];
coordinates = Through[weatherStations["Coordinates"]];
rain =
WeatherData[#, "TotalPrecipitation", {{2017, 8, 17}, {2017, 9, 3}, "Day"}] & 
/@ 
weatherStations;
maxRain =
(Max /@ DeleteCases[Through[rain["Values"]], Missing[_], {-2}, Heads -> 
 True]) /. 
{"Values" -> 0., -∞ -> 0.};
data = MapThread[{Sequence @@ #1, #2} &, {coordinates, maxRain}];

Show[
ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}],
Graphics3D[{Red, Ellipsoid[{32.7942, -96.7655, 2.}, .015 {16, 18, 80}]}],
ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

The red dot is Dallas and you can see the rainfall is accumulated mostly south-southeast. However, the graph isn't pretty enough to present. I want to color the surface of the graph based on values of `WindSpeed`. I want higher values of wind-speed red and lower values of wind speed yellow. The values of wind speed can probably be generated the same way as I have `"TotalPrecipitation"`. Does anyone who how to do color the graph based on values of wind speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply a pure function to `ColorFunction`. This function will be supplied the absolute (relative) coordinates when `ColorFunctionScaling` is set to `False` (`True`: default).

It is more convenient to work with absolute coordinates: we get `x` and `y` and simply look up the wind speed value. I'm using a simple scaling function for the color that interpolates between yellow and red.

I've not unset the `Mesh`. On one hand it makes the plot look sorta' ugly. On the other hand, it is hard to get a sense of perspective without it since the colors don't match up with the heights (or maybe my eyes are just bad).

```
dallas = CityData[{"Dallas", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}, "Coordinates"];

With[{n = 400}, weatherStations = WeatherData[{dallas, n}]];
coordinates = Through[weatherStations["Coordinates"]];
getSeries[s_] := 
  WeatherData[#, s, {{2017, 8, 17}, {2017, 9, 3}, "Day"}] & /@ 
   weatherStations;

(* Warning: these will take a few minutes depending on your internet connection *)
rain = getSeries["TotalPrecipitation"];
windSpeed = getSeries["WindSpeed"];

maxValues[series_] := (Max /@ 
     DeleteCases[Through[series["Values"]], Missing[_], {-2}, 
      Heads -> True]) /. {"Values" -> 0., -∞ -> 0.};

maxRain = maxValues[rain];
maxWindSpeed = maxValues[windSpeed];
allMaxWindSpeed = Max@maxWindSpeed;

windSpeedTable = 
  Association[Rule @@@ Transpose[{coordinates, maxWindSpeed}]];

redYellow[t_] := RGBColor[1, 1 - t^(1/4), 0];
colorFn = redYellow[windSpeedTable[{#1, #2}]/allMaxWindSpeed] &;

rainData = MapThread[{Sequence @@ #1, #2} &, {coordinates, maxRain}]

Show[
 ListPlot3D[
  rainData
  , PlotRange -> All
  , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}
  , ColorFunction -> colorFn
  , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
  ]
 , Graphics3D@{Purple, 
   Ellipsoid[{32.7942, -96.7655, 2.}, .015 {16, 18, 80}]}
 , ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: rain 3d plot colored with wind speed]

One easy way to play with the "splotchiness" of the colors is by tweaking the power in `t^(1/4)`; increasing the exponent will make the splotches stand out more.